# Is it possible use aws-amplify without cognito in react web application

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am new to AWS platform. I am establishing API connection from front end using react js .
Here I got API details but not Cognito details to make connection. I did tried to establish the connection without congnito but it did not worked. Is there any way to connect AWS API gateway without congnito.

Please help with this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

We needed to use Cognito as well in order to use API key;

```
"auth": {
        "xxxxx": {
            "service": "Cognito",
            "providerPlugin": "awscloudformation",
```

You can also use the Cognito Identity SDK which Amplify uses indirectly: https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-cognito-identity-js

The AWSjs SDK can also be used I believe, but you will have a rough time making up for its shortcomings like sessions.

But from what we've seen, going with a Cognito pool just works best with Amplify.

Comment: If API dose not need authentication than also need to use Cognito ?